# How to change regex pattern from textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

How I could set the variable `pat` to act as variable `patt1`? I want write in the textbox just "abe" and change from `var patt1 = /\b[abc]+\b/g;` to `var patt1 = /\b[abe]+\b/g;`. Is that possible?

```
<html>
    <body onload="onload();">


    <input type="text" id="lol"/>
    <input type="button" VALUE="Resitve" onclick="myFunction();"/>

    <p id="alert"></p>

    <script>
    var pat;


    function myFunction() {
        pat = document.getElementById("lol").value;

        var str = "abc ab abe abeee";
        var patt1 = /\b[abc]+\b/g;

        var result = str.match(pat);
        document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = result;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your regex can be in string form. Just pass the regex to the match function as a concatenated string instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `RegExp` object:

```html
<html>
    <body onload="onload();">


    <input type="text" id="lol"/>
    <input type="button" VALUE="Resitve" onclick="myFunction();"/>

    <p id="alert"></p>

    <script>
    var pat;


    function myFunction() {
        pat = document.getElementById("lol").value;

        var str = "abc ab abe abeee";
        var patt1 = new RegExp("\\b[" + pat + "]+\\b","g");

        var result = patt1.exec(str);
        document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = result;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Or you can simply make the pattern in your code as string:

```html
<html>
    <body onload="onload();">


    <input type="text" id="lol"/>
    <input type="button" VALUE="Resitve" onclick="myFunction();"/>

    <p id="alert"></p>

    <script>
    var pat;


    function myFunction() {
    pat = document.getElementById("lol").value;

    var str = "abc ab abe abeee";
    var patt1 = "\\b[" + pat + "]+\\b";

    var result = str.match(patt1);
    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = result;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

If you want to truly find all matches, you will need to call the `exec` function in a loop:

```html
<html>
    <body onload="onload();">


    <input type="text" id="lol"/>
    <input type="button" VALUE="Resitve" onclick="myFunction();"/>

    <p id="alert"></p>

    <script>
    var pat;


    function myFunction() {
        pat = document.getElementById("lol").value;

        var str = "abc ab abe abeee";
        var patt1 = new RegExp("\\b[" + pat + "]+\\b","g");

        var result;
        var display = document.getElementById("alert");
        display.innerHTML = "";
        while(result = patt1.exec(str)){
            display.innerHTML += result + "<br/>";
        }
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem and bring a new one. This work only for first string in "var str..". I want a combination of all.

Comment: You just need to find the matches in a loop. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`String.prototype.match()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

> str.match(regexp)
>
> **regexp**
>
> If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, it is implicitly converted to a
>   RegExp by using new RegExp(obj).

So, passing your regex as a concatenated string should work fine. i.e., instead of this:

```
var patt1 = /\b[abc]+\b/g;
```

Use this:

```
var patt1 = "/\b[abc]+\b/g";
```

And amend that string as you see fit!